# Correctly get win-1252 text stored in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, encoding, windows-1252

I have a legacy `WPF` app `(on .NET 4.7)` that reads files from the drive as string in `win 1252 encoding`. Then it stores the string in a text column in a database table.

I have a new console app `(.NET Core 6)` and I am trying to get the column which contains the contents of a file in `1252 encoded` text and create the same file on another file system.

However, doing that, the files end up corrupted when I try to open them although I can open them without a problem from the legacy app.

Here is the code that I get the contents from the text column and then use it to write a new file in the file system:

```
var content = _dBContext.Docs.Where(e => e.Id == id).Select(e => e.Contents).SingleOrDefault();
byte[] encodedAnsi = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(content);
string correctedUtf = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedAnsi);
byte[] correctedArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(correctedUtf);
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, correctedArr);
```

Also here is the legacy code that stores the file contents in the database:

```
Function GetContent(ByVal FName As String) As String

Dim buffa As String
Dim Input As FileStream = New FileStream(FName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim Bytes(CInt(Input.Length - 1)) As Byte
Input.Read(Bytes, 0, CInt(Input.Length))
Input.Close()
buffa = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Bytes)
ReadFileX = buffa
If Len(buffa) = 0 Then ReadFileX = ""
End Function

.......... 
Dim content As String = GetContent(filepath)
..........

Update Docs Set Contents = " & content & " Where Id = " & id
```

My goal is to just correctly write the file in a new filesystem by getting the file contents from the Text column and therefore i should be able to open those files when i execute them. Now they seem corrupted when i try to open them.

Could someone help?

Although the code is

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Bytes)
```

I run on powershell on the server the legacy app is running:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

and I got back that the default encoding is win-1252 so I guess I am not making a wrong assumption there

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(filename, content)` should suffice (assuming you really do want a UTF-8 encoded file). You don't have to concern yourself with encoding here, since the database is taking care of that -- what you get back is a string, the underlying encoding is no longer your concern. The code you cite is handling the encoding when *reading* the file. If the text appears incorrect when selecting it, that means it wasn't read/stored correctly to begin with, but that's a separate problem.

Comment: From what you're writing it seems to suggest you actually want to end up with a file encoded as Windows-1252 so your application can read it, not UTF-8, in which case `File.WriteAllBytes(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(content))` suffices. Don't ever use `Encoding.Default` if you can help it, since this value *can* be different per system depending on locale -- if your legacy code uses it that's still no reason to copy that approach.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It seems to be stored correctly because the legacy app is able to create/open the file. I am not using the Default encoding in the new app - see the code above - but yes the legacy app unfortunately uses it. My goal is to just correctly write the file in a new filesystem by getting the file contents from the Text column and therefore i should be able to open those files when i execute them. Now they seem corrupted when i try to open them.

Comment: Start comparing bytes, or encodings, for the "corrupted" vs. the "uncorrupted" case. A hex editor may be of help here. Double check also that the legacy code your posted is *really* correct/complete -- if it *literally* does `Update Docs Set Contents = " & content & "` then it isn't storing the contents of the file, but the contents of the file *when interpreted as a string literal*, meaning it would have to start and end with a single quote (and be a huge vector for SQL injection).

Comment: _"the files end up corrupted"_ - using which editor? And which encoding does that editor use? Textiles don't announce their encoding, editors have to guess.

Comment: @CodeCaster If for example it is a msg file outlook cannot open it. Same for docx files for example with word.

Comment: Outlook's .msg files and Office .docx files are binary files. (.docx files in particular are essentially .zip archives containing multiple folders-worth of .xml and other files.)  If you're trying to deal with them as text files with character encodings of course they're going to be messed up.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning however i did not write that code and i have to find a solution so is there something you would propose?

Comment: How do you get the chocolate flavoring back out of a glass of milk after you've poured some in and stirred it up? You cannot. Whether or not it was the intention that code was originally written to only deal with cp1252 encoded text files, so don't try to use it for binary files nor even text files with other encodings.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Since the legacy app is able to open the files correctly i guess that i could find a way to make it work too. No?